# JFrame not adding graphics from separate class

Tags: java, swing

I'm quite new to swing, and I'm having an issue with graphics not showing up in my JFrame. What I should be seeing is a blue rectangle slowly moving downwards through the frame, and behind it is a plain white background. However, when I run my main class, all I see is a plain JFrame. This is my code:

`Execute` class

```
public class Execute {

public static void main (String[ ] args) {
    GUI gui = new GUI();
    gui.createFrame(800,600);

    ElevatorOne e1 = new ElevatorOne();
    e1.addElevatorOne();
}
}
```

`ElevatorOne` class (Where the graphics should be initialized and added)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ElevatorOne extends GUI{

int y = 100;

public void addElevatorOne() {

    drawElevatorOne drawE1 = new drawElevatorOne();
    frame.getContentPane().add(drawE1);

    for(int i = 0; i < 130; i++) {
        y++;

        drawE1.repaint();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class drawElevatorOne extends JPanel{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawRect(200,y,40,60);
    }
}

}
```

And finally, my `GUI` class (where `frame` is created)
import javax.swing.JFrame;

```
public class GUI {

JFrame frame = new JFrame();

public void createFrame(int x, int y) {
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(x, y);
}

}
```

Comment: Your addElevatorOne is likely going to block the EDT, meaning it I'll only paint the last position after a short delay. Consider using a Swing Timer instead to do the animation. You're also violating the paint chain, which could result in paint artefacts and other weirdness, make sure you're calling super.paintComponent before you do any custom painting

Comment: 1) Add components (and call pack) **before** the frame is visible. 2)  Use a Swing based `Timer` to do animation in a GUI.  Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: @MadProgrammer in the swing timer, would I call the `repaint()` method every time it repeats itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you've got an accepted answer, I do take issue with that answer and feel impelled to add my two cents:

- I see no purpose to your having a GUI class and then having Elevator1 extend it. If you want Elevator1 to use a JFrame, then have it create a JFrame as there really is no need or benefit from your inheritance.
- Myself, I'd have Elevator1 extend JPanel and then have it draw in its own paintComponent method, thus eliminating the need  for drawElevatorOne inner class (which should be named `DrawElevatorOne` to adhere to Java naming conventions).
- You are using Thread.sleep in a Swing GUI which is extremely risky to do. The only reason this works is because it is being called in the main thread. If your code were properly created and set up to start and create GUI components in the Swing event thread, this would and should fail since it would put the Swing event thread to sleep. Don't do this, don't call Thread.sleep in a method that has any risk of being called in the Swing event thread.
- Instead use a Swing Timer to manage your delay.
- Don't forget to (almost) always call the `super.paintComponent(g)` method within your oeverride. To not do this breaks the Swing painting chain and risks significant hard to debug side effects.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ElevatorTest {
   private static final int PREF_W = 800;
   private static final int PREF_H = 600;

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      MyElevator mainPanel = new MyElevator(PREF_W, PREF_H);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Elevator Test");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // start everything on the Swing event thread
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class MyElevator extends JPanel {
   private static final Color BACKGROUND = Color.white;
   private static final int ELEVATOR_X = 200;
   private static final int ELEVATOR_W = 40;
   private static final int ELEVATOR_H = 60;
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 50;
   public static final int MAX_ELEVATOR_Y = 130;
   private static final Color ELEVATOR_COLOR = Color.blue;
   private int prefW;
   private int prefH;
   private int elevatorY = 0;

   public MyElevator(int prefW, int prefH) {
      this.prefW = prefW;
      this.prefH = prefH;
      setBackground(BACKGROUND);

      new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener()).start();
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      // Don't forget to call the super method
      super.paintComponent(g);

      g.setColor(ELEVATOR_COLOR);
      g.fillRect(ELEVATOR_X, elevatorY, ELEVATOR_W, ELEVATOR_H);
   }

   // to help size our GUI properly
   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      Dimension superSz = super.getPreferredSize();
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return superSz;
      }
      int w = Math.max(superSz.width, prefW);
      int h = Math.max(superSz.height, prefH);
      return new Dimension(w, h);
   }

   private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (elevatorY >= MAX_ELEVATOR_Y) {
            // if elevator at max, stop thimer
            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
         } else {
            // advance elevator and draw it
            elevatorY++;
            repaint();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ElevatorOne class extends GUI. Therefore it inherits all of the functionality of GUI, yet you create both of them. This is probably what you intended to do:

edit: I ran this code and indeed there is a box moving as you specify.

```
public class Execute {

public static void main (String[ ] args) {
    //    GUI gui = new GUI();
    //    gui.createFrame(800,600);

    ElevatorOne e1 = new ElevatorOne();
    e1.createFrame(800, 600);
    e1.addElevatorOne();
}
```

}