# Animation not adding to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm new to java swing, so forgive me if my mistake is extremely obvious. What my code is supposed to do here is create **one** JFrame and animate two boxes moving upwards through the frame side by side. However, I'm seeing only one box (the blue box created by the `ElevatorOne` class). The green box (from `ElevatorTwo`) is not appearing. This is my code:

`Execute` class (with the `main` method):

```
public class Execute {

public static void main (String[ ] args) {

    Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            ElevatorOne e1 = new ElevatorOne();
            e1.createFrame(800, 600);
            e1.addElevatorOne();
        }
    };

    Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            ElevatorTwo e2 = new ElevatorTwo();
            e2.addElevatorTwo();
        }
    };

    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();

}

}
```

`ElevatorOne` class (the one that draws the blue box):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ElevatorOne extends GUI{

int y = 400;

public void addElevatorOne() {

    DrawElevatorOne drawE1 = new DrawElevatorOne();
    frame.getContentPane().add(drawE1);

    for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
        y--;

        drawE1.repaint();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (Exception ex) { }
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DrawElevatorOne extends JPanel{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawRect(200,y,80,120);
    }
}

}
```

`ElevatorTwo` class (the one that draws the green box, which is **not** appearing in my JFrame):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ElevatorTwo extends GUI{

int y = 400;

public void addElevatorTwo() {
    DrawElevatorTwo drawE2 = new DrawElevatorTwo();
    frame.getContentPane().add(drawE2);

    for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
        y--;

        drawE2.repaint();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DrawElevatorTwo extends JPanel{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawRect(600,y,80,120);
    }
}

}
```

And finally, the `GUI` class (where `frame` is created):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GUI {

JFrame frame = new JFrame();

public void createFrame(int x, int y) {
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(x, y);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Comment: Code is now consolidated into 2 classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was commented on in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902987/jframe-not-adding-graphics-from-separate-class)...

> Your addElevatorOne is likely going to block the EDT, meaning it I'll only paint the last position after a short delay. Consider using a Swing Timer instead to do the animation...

And as you asked...

> in the swing timer, would I call the repaint() method every time it repeats itself?

Yes.  The Swing `Timer` would act as a psudo loop, each time it ticks, you would update the `y` variable, check to see if it exceeds your requirements and stop the `Timer` if it does and call `repaint`

Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Also, Swing is NOT thread safe, this means that you should NEVER modify the UI in anyway from outside of the context of the EDT.  The reason we suggest using Swing `Timer` is because it calls the registered `ActionListener` within the context of the EDT, making it safe to make modifications to the UI

Let's rethink the problem.  Your code is a little convoluted, making it difficult to comprehend.  Instead of using all the "multiple" frames, lets concentrate on making a `Elevator` which knows how to move...

```
public class Elevator extends JPanel {

    private int y = 0;
    private int delta = 1;
    private Color fillColor;

    public Elevator(Color color, boolean goingDown) {
        fillColor = color;

        if (goingDown) {
            y = 0;
            delta = 1;
        } else {
            y = getPreferredSize().height - 120;
            delta = -1;
        }

        Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                y += delta;
                if (y + 120 > getHeight()) {
                    y = getHeight() - 120;
                    delta *= -1;
                } else if (y < 0) {
                    y = 0;
                    delta *= -1;
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(81, 120 * 3);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(fillColor);
        g.drawRect(0, y, 80, 120);
    }

}
```

Pretty simple, it's `JPanel`, with has custom painting to paint the actual elevator, it set's up it's preferred size to the width of the elevator car, but three times the height (three stories) and has it's own `Timer` to move the car.

The constructor allows you to customise the color and the initial direction of movement

It's a self contained unit of work.  So long as you don't have to many elevators running simultaneously, this will work okay.  If you need lots of them, then you will need a central `Timer` from which all the elevators would be notified of a "timer" event, but that's a discussion for another question.

Now, you just need to show them...

[image: Going up or down]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new Elevator(Color.GREEN, true));
                frame.add(new Elevator(Color.BLUE, false));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your time. I have a clarifying question: 1) What does the `try/catch` statement in the `public Test()` section do?

Comment: It loads the look and feel, this process can throw a bunch of exceptions, typically I'm not to worried about them as I'm loading the "system" look and feel (windows in my example). I have a pathological hatred if the "default" metal look and feel

Comment: One last thing -- what exactly does the `EventQueue.invokeLater` phrase do? Shouldn't i just create a JFrame first thing?

Comment: Swing is not thread safe, you can't guarantee what thread you method is called in, so, you need to synch the creation of the UI into the context of the EDT.

Comment: Sorry I'm still bothering you, but I have one more question. What does the `y` variable do in the `Elevators` class?

Comment: It determines the `y` (vertical) position that the `Rectangle` should be painted within the `JPanel`